# What is the package name of Gnome Web / Epiphany?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, epiphany

I want to install Gnome web using command line on Ubuntu Deskop 1804. I cannot use software center. Using apt not snap.

Unfortunately Ubuntu software center does not display package names. Only version information.

I tried apt install epiphany, gnome-web-browser without result.

What is the package name of Gnome Web / Epiphany? This seems to be a carefully guarded secret.

Answer (score 0):

The package name is `epiphany-browser`.

```
[onknows:~/git/tpelcm/ansible] master(+12/-7)* ± sudo apt-cache madison epiphany-browser
epiphany-browser | 3.28.6-0ubuntu1 | http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
epiphany-browser | 3.28.1-1ubuntu1 | http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```